# Install OpenCV3 under Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, opencv3, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to use a node for detecting markers that is depending on OpenCV3. Since ROS Indigo has only openCV2.4.8 preinstaleld the downloaded node fails on "catkin_make". I was searching for an easy way to install OpenVC3, but since i'm new to linux and ROS i wasn't able to install it.

Basically i guess this is what i need for my project:

http://sauravag.com/2015/03/how-to-tracking-aruco-marker-using-a-usb-webcam-and-ro/

```
Step 2:
git clone https://github.com/pal-robotics/aruco_ros.git
-> Cloning into 'aruco_ros'...
-> remote: Counting objects: 558, done.
-> remote: Total 558 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 558
-> Receiving objects: 100% (558/558), 407.44 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
-> Resolving deltas: 100% (307/307), done.
-> Checking connectivity... done.
```

So far everything seems to be ok. The folder has been created and is also filled with lots of files. But than :

```
step 4: 
catkin_make install
-> ...
-> (lots of lines without any error)
-> ...
-> CMake Error at aruco_ros/aruco/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
->     Could not find a configuration file for package "OpenCV" that is 
->     compatible with requested version "3".
-> The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:
->     /usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake, version: 2.4.8
```

Tried to do an update (apt-get update) and tried again with same result. So i just tried the next tutorial here:

http://external-camera-tf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

But already the first line failes:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-opencv3
-> Reading package lists... Done
-> Building dependency tree       
-> Reading state information... Done
-> E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-opencv3
```

So it seems like there is no easy way to get OpenCV3 running under **ROS Indigo** with **Ubuntu 14.04** (trusty), right? Or am i missing something? Because on other posts, people only complain about the problems after they installed the additional version like [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/214043/use-ros-indigo-opencv3-alongside-248/) and also [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/issues/91). So it must be possible to get it working (even if  maybe not by an easy way)

Does anybody know how? Anybody reading this using OpenCV3 (maybe even with the marker detection) and is still knowing what steps has been done?

Thanks to everybody taking some time to read through this.

.

.

.

Update1:
Ok, following the tutorial of the second [link](http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/) pavel92 suggested and a few dozens of hundreds of lines in the terminal later the installation seems to be complete. I saw a few warnings but no error at the end. As i now try to catkin_make i get something different:

```
/home/(username)/catkin_ws/src/aruco_ros/aruco/src/aruco/cvdrawingutils.cpp:172:82: 
error: ‘CV_AA’ was not declared in this scope
         cv::line(Image,imagePoints[i],imagePoints[i+4],Scalar(0,0,255,255),1,CV_AA);
```

this seems to be the case for: CV_AA (9x), CV_BGR2GRAY (1x) , assert (3x) (13x errors total)

At least for the first two they seem to be defines (?).

In the makefile (@: /home/(username)/catkin_ws/src/aruco_ros/aruco) all the suggestions by pavel92 are already included:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(aruco)
find_package(catkin)

find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)     <-----

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES aruco
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}       <-----
)

add_library(aruco
  src/aruco/arucofidmarkers.cpp
  src/aruco/cvdrawingutils.cpp
  src/aruco/marker.cpp
  ...
)

target_link_libraries(aruco
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})     <----

add_executable(optimalmarkers
  ...
...
```

Since the package was asking for OpenCV3 from the first moment on i was expecting the code to be using the correct syntax (as far as i understand there were some mayor changes done form 2.x to 3.x on how to call functions and stuff). So, did i forget one step? Point to some header file where the defines are made?

Sorry for asking such noop questions :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297783/install-opencv3-under-indigo-on-ubuntu-14.04/) by [-LD-](https://answers.ros.org/users/35853/-ld-/) on ROS Answers with karma: 135 on 2018-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/) and [this](http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/) step by step tutorials show how to install OpenCV3 on Ubuntu 14.04.
You can build OpenCV3 from source and include the following in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries(foo_node
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

You can recompile cv_bridge against OpenCV3 in the workspace. Just clone [cv_bridge](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv) in your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [-LD-](https://answers.ros.org/users/35853/-ld-/) on 2018-07-18**:
Thanks for the links. I feared that i have to get OpenCV working separated first and than telling ROS where to find it. At the other hand the second link seems to be fairly easy. Will try it right away.

**Comment by [-LD-](https://answers.ros.org/users/35853/-ld-/) on 2018-07-18**:
Almost worked perfectly. I updates my original post. May i please you to read through it? Maybe you know an answer for the new error? But anyway, thanks for the links and your time.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2018-07-18**:
Try changing CV_AA for cv::CV_AA

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-07-19**:
Do you have the header, `#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>` included?

CV_AA and CV_BGR2GRAY are defined in OpenCV2.4. In OpenCV3.4 is LINE_AA and CV_BGR2GRAY is cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY. A lot of constants have changed there, like most of the CV_ prefixes were changed to cv:: namespace.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-07-20**:
Let me know if this solved your problem

**Comment by [-LD-](https://answers.ros.org/users/35853/-ld-/) on 2018-07-20**:
Sorry, i don't have access to the PC with the programs all the time. Next time will be Monday. I will write an update then.

**Comment by [-LD-](https://answers.ros.org/users/35853/-ld-/) on 2018-07-24**:
Ok, seems like the errors i'm currently dealing with don't have anything in common with the original question. Yes, all errors were caused by the openCV2.4.8 defines. Still weird since the lib was asking for 3.0, but at least i could simply change them (just as you pointed out).